# ARM assembly, multiplying without MUL instruction

Tags: assembly, arm

I have researched this extensively, and have not found any answers. I need to multiply a*17 without using the multiply instructions in ARM assembly language. I understand you can use RSB, but how to set up the values or use the LSL# part is confusing to me. Any help would be great!!

Comment: How extensive has your study been? (http://www.peter-cockerell.net/aalp/html/ch-3.html) --> `add r1, r1, r1 LSL #4` ??

Comment: `RSB a, a, a LSL #4` would calculate `a*15 == (a<<4 - a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with comments but just a quick tip, compilers are generally really good at optimizing multiplications by constants.

So you can just use an `arm-*-*-gcc` toolchain to get this kind of answers.

```
$ cat m17.c 
int f(int i) {
    return i * 17;
}

$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -O3 -S m17.c
$ cat m17.s
        <skipped>
f:
    add r0, r0, r0, lsl #4
    bx  lr
    <skipped>
```

and a terrible joke: *Use the Tools, Luke!*